# ggplot and sf package: broken polygons after projection

Tags: r, sf, ggplot2

My standard hack for fixing broken polygons after re-projection (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77298627/strange-behavior-with-ggplot-sf-package-and-orthographic-projection) does NOT seem to work for the Albers Equal-area projection. What am I missing? Cross posting to stackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380896/ggplot-and-sf-package-broken-polygons-after-projection

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
library(lwgeom)
library(mapview)

## load background map of the world 
data("World") ## get built-in data from the tmap package
world.sf <- World
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=world.sf, fill="white") ## looks fine

world.sf %>% st_transform("+proj=ortho +lat_0=40") %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(fill="white")## missing polygons

## standard hack for broken polygons
world.sf <- st_cast(world.sf, 'MULTILINESTRING') %>%
  st_cast('LINESTRING', do_split=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(npts = npts(geometry, by_feature = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(npts > 3) %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON')

world.sf %>% st_transform("+proj=ortho +lat_0=40") %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(fill="white")## looks good


world.sf %>% st_transform(crs="+proj=aea +lon_0=12.65625 +lat_1=32.7988379 +lat_2=50.7766668 +lat_0=41.7877524 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_sf(fill="white") ## broken polygon

## standard hack doesn't work
```

Comment: it seems your "cross posting to" mention rolls into a repeat of the code block?

Comment: Thanks! It's fixed

Comment: When you post large chunks of code that you say cause errors can you please include the error message, the plot, or describe what goes wrong? Just saying "doesn't work" isn't very helpful. Its also helpful if you don't use `library(tidyverse)` - best practice is to only include packages you use - in this case it looks like simply `dplyr`. Also try plotting with `plot` and see if the problem really is ggplot (as stated in the title) or its really in the sf data itself.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that you are trying to draw the whole world on a conical projection, and Antarctica is basically stretched out to the edge of the cone, assuming I'm seeing the same as you. Drop Antarctica and you get a better map, but there's still a discontinuity at the top because that's where the cone has been split - the graticule lines are discontinuous and really the whole plot needs masking over that area...

Comment: Thanks! My current hack `world.sf <- gisco_get_countries()` and then 
`world.sf[which(world.sf$continent%in%c("Europe","Africa","Asia")),]` which does the trick